# How can I update multiple items simultaneously in Qt Quick?

Tags: qt, qtquick2

I have a Qt Quick view that contains several custom `QQuickItem`-derived objects in it. When I detect that the appearance of those items should change, I call `QQuickItem::update()`, which calls `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()`.

There are points in my application where several items change state at the same time, and I'd like to render those changes simultaneously on the same frame. Is there a way to synchronize multiple calls to `QQuickItem::update()` to ensure that the actual calls to `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()` are performed on the same frame?

Comment: In a proper design it should happen automatically. If something changes on the "data" side, all the relevant items will be updated in the same event loop cycle.

Comment: How so? If the rendering is controlled by a thread internal to Qt (the "renderer thread"), why would I be sure that multiple calls to `QQuickItem::update()` (which do not occur in the renderer thread) would be synchronized like I want? Seems to me that explicit synchronization would need to be done in order to achieve this.

Comment: What makes you think they won't be? I don't see a valid reason for the update to be spread over more than a single event loop cycle. The change will be notified in the main thread, the next cycle of the rendering thread the affected objects will be updated.

Comment: I'm trying to rely upon documented behavior, especially when multithreading is thrown into the mix. What is there to make me think that multiple calls to `QQuickItem::update()` in one thread would be somehow synchronized with the operation of the render thread? There's nothing in the documentation for `QQuickItem::update()` that indicates that anything is deferred to the main event loop or anything of the sort. For all I know, the first call to the update function could trigger the render thread to immediately start rendering the new frame, before I can get the second update call in.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html

Comment: I'm familiar with that document. Specifically, [this image](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/sg-renderloop-threaded.jpg) shows a flow chart of the threaded rendering loop. That diagram, and the documentation surrounding it, don't mention any implicit synchronization between the UI thread and the render thread. Based on this description, I'm left to assume that subsequent calls to `QQuickItem::update()` in one thread will not necessarily be handled in the same frame by the render thread.

Comment: Yes, that graph makes it look like any change will force a frame change, thus delaying additional changes, which sounds kinda fishy IMO. Maybe the graph is buggy, because the efficient thing would be for each object to mark the scene as dirty, and next time the renderer produces a frame, it reflects all changes at once. Trying `item.color = "red; item.color = "blue"` doesn't show a red, just a blue, so no, changes do not immediately force new frame updates, otherwise you'd see a frame of red before the blue frame.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it won't necessarily start a new frame immediately upon a call to `update()`, but there's no guarantee about *when* it will (since it's on a different thread, it might start between my two updates). I'm trying to determine whether there is some documented way for me to batch multiple updates that should be rendered together on the same frame.

Comment: I still think it is logical that regardless of the count of changes, this will simply cause the renderer to make a new frame when the time comes for a new frame. The renderer won't read changes from the main thread until it finishes its own event loop cycle, and any change of data will be reflected by all items in the same frame. I cannot give you guarantee. But you will most likely not get a definite answer here, so either go through the source (good luck with that BTW :) ) or ask in the Qt mailing lists, where the core developers dwell, for some reason they are not frequenting here at SO.